# variables do not appear in right why using writeFileSync nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to put a variable as `${Y}` in but in the output I got (how can I write variable `${Y}`)
instead of the data in `Y` is someone have any solution?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Y = fs.readFileSync('./txt/input.txt','utf-8')

const Z='how can i write variable ${Y}';
fs.writeFileSync('./txt/output.txt',Z);
console.log('File written!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of just a string (backticks instead of single quotes):

```
const Z=`how can i write variable ${Y}`;
```

Comment: yeah it works thanks

Comment: @HossamThapet welcome